# No gradients provided for any variable for custom segmentation loss function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function, gradient

I created a segmentation function. `y` are the mnist labels and `y_` is softmax the prediction result, `pen_less` and `pen_more` are two penalty parameters.

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(
    tf.greater(tf.to_float(tf.argmax(y, 1)), tf.to_float(tf.argmax(y_, 1))),
    tf.pow(pen_less, tf.to_float(tf.argmax(y, 1)) - tf.to_float(tf.argmax(y_, 1))),
    tf.pow(pen_more, tf.to_float(tf.argmax(y, 1)) - tf.to_float(tf.argmax(y_, 1)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: so `tf.where` is differentiable if you pass all three parameters. I assume then your problem lies in the argmaxes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([0, 1, 2])
tf.gradients(tf.argmax(x), x)
```

Output:

> LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'ArgMax' (op type: ArgMax)

If you want a differentiable loss function, you need to avoid argmax operations or find a smart way to get a suitable pseudogradient.

Comment: I also thought it was this problem before.，but some function like: loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.greater(y, y_), (y - y_)*loss_more, (y_-y)*loss_less)) can work. i don't know why.

Comment: Edited my answer.